# Debugging CrashLoopBackOff for an image running as root in openshift origin

Tags: openshift-origin

I wanted to start an ubuntu container on a open shift origin. I have my local registry and pulling from it is successful. The container starts but immediately throws CrashLoopBackOff and stops. The ubuntu image that I have runs as root

```
Started container with docker id 28250a528e69
Created container with docker id 28250a528e69
Successfully pulled image "ns1.myregistry.com:5000/ubuntu@sha256:6d9a2a1bacdcb2bd65e36b8f1f557e89abf0f5f987ba68104bcfc76103a08b86"
pulling image "ns1.myregistry.com:5000/ubuntu@sha256:6d9a2a1bacdcb2bd65e36b8f1f557e89abf0f5f987ba68104bcfc76103a08b86"
Error syncing pod, skipping: failed to "StartContainer" for "ubuntu" with CrashLoopBackOff: "Back-off 5m0s restarting failed container=ubuntu pod=ubuntu-2-suy6p_testproject(69af5cd9-5dff-11e6-940e-0800277bbed5)"
```

The container runs with restricted privilege. I dont know how to start the pod with a privileged mode, so edited my restricted mode as follows so that my image with root access will run

```
> NAME         PRIV      CAPS      SELINUX    RUNASUSER   FSGROUP   
> SUPGROUP   PRIORITY   READONLYROOTFS   VOLUMES restricted   true     
> []        RunAsAny   RunAsAny    RunAsAny   RunAsAny   <none>    
> false            [configMap downwardAPI emptyDir persistentVolumeClaim
> secret]
```

But still I couldnt successfully start my container ?

Comment: Did you try to perform `oadm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default` inside your project and scale your pod down or delete it (`oc delete pod xxx --grace-period=0` and back up?

Comment: No. I tried it now.  
# ./oc whoami
test
# ./oadm --config=/home/ubuntu/Openshift/openshift-origin-server-v1.3.0-alpha.2-983578e-linux-64bit/openshift.local.config/master/admin.kubeconfig policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default

Then deployed a new pod. Still the same issue

Answer (score 2):

There are two commands that helpful for crashloopbackoff debugging.

`oc debug pod/your-pod-name` will create a very similar pod and exec into it.  You can look at the different options for launching it, some deal with SCC options.  You can also use dc, rc, is, most things that can stamp out pods.

`oc logs -p pod/your-pod-name` will retrieve the logs from the last run of the pod, which may have useful information too.